# Failed to compare UTF-8 chrs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm using Ruby - Cucumber for automation.

I'm trying to send Japanese chars as a parameter to the user defined function to verify in db.

Below is the statement what I have used :
x=$objDB.run_select_query_verifyText('select name from xxxx where id=1','ごせり槎ゃぱ')

In the run_select_query_verifyText() function I have the code to connect db and get the records from db and it will verify the the text which is passed as a parameter(Japanese chars. )

This function returns true if the string is match with table data in DB else false.

But I'm getting always false and I found that the Japanese string is converting as "??????" while comparing the data.

Note: My program is working fine with English chars.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely with character encodings. The database returns the content in a different encoding that the Ruby string you are working with. You need to figure out what the db encoding is and make sure both are the same.

If you are using ruby 1.9, you can check the encoding current encoding with `yourstring.encoding` and change it to e.g. UTF-8 with `yourstring.encode("UTF-8")`.
If you are on ruby 1.8 things are bit more tricky as the String class doesn't natively support encodings. You can use e.g. the [character-encodings](http://rubygems.org/gems/character-encodings) gem to work around this.